# Make a left border move to center in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, simple-html-dom

I am making a change in my current `div` such that I need a **vertical line** at the **middle** of my `div`. So, I saw many **solutions** in which they are making a left border and with the help of left property they are moving it **50%** of the left (which is actually is in middle).

Here is how I am making my **`div:`**

```
if (id == "Metricbar" ) {
      var Parentdiv = document.getElementById("homeContainer");
      var rowDiv = document.createElement("article");
      rowDiv.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12");
      rowDiv.style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
      rowDiv.style.marginBottom = "1px";
      rowDiv.style.marginTop = "1px";
      rowDiv.style.borderLeft = "2px solid #ddd";
      Parentdiv.appendChild(rowDiv);


      var ctrlDiv = document.createElement("div");
      ctrlDiv.setAttribute("data-widget-editbutton", "false");
      ctrlDiv.className = "jarviswidget";
      ctrlDiv.setAttribute("data-widget-fullscreenbutton", "false");
      ctrlDiv.id = id;
      var temp = $compile(ctrlDiv)($scope);
      angular.element(rowDiv).append(temp);
      rowDiv.appendChild(ctrlDiv);
}
```

My question is how will I move it to the **center**. Is there any way to do that?

**I have tried:**

```
rowDiv.style.borderLeft.marginLeft = "50%";
rowDiv.style.borderLeft.Left = "50%";
rowDiv.style.borderLeft.leftMargin = "50%";
```

But none of this is helping. Can anybody point me in the right direction.

**HTML File :**

```
<section id="widget-grid" class="" style="padding-left:13px;padding-right:13px;">
   <div class="row" id="homeContainer"></div>
   <div class="modaldialogs" style="display: none">
      <div class="center">
         <img alt="" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

But I am using this div multiple times. I am here checking on the basis of id.

I want this black line as shown in **image**
[image: What I want]

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I have shared

Comment: Can you add an image showing the desired effect?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I have added the desired image

Comment: And you want to use the `article` element for that?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody this is code which is already developed and I just have to include a vertical line in the existing code. I don't have any desire to use article. Article is what making the text box. In the box I need to have a vertical line

Comment: Why not use a background image to accomplish this? Just use `background = "url(square1x1coloredpixel.gif) repeat-y 50% 50%"` or something. Also, this would work: `rowDiv.style.marginLeft = "50%";`, but not `rowDiv.style.borderLeft.marginLeft = "50%";` - althought it might not be the desired effect.

Comment: Stuff like `rowDiv.style.borderLeft.marginLeft = "50%";` just makes no sense at all; it is no surprise that this is “not working”. You can not set multiple CSS properties that way, you need to set them individually.

Comment: @CBroe yes I tried setting individually but it was also not working

Comment: @somethinghereyou are correct rowDiv.style.marginLeft = "50%" this will move the whole div to 50 % left which is I don't want.  I am looking how to do with image. Could you paste a link for the same?

Comment: You can not “move” a border to a different position on its own, you can only move the whole element that has the border. A background image would be one way to achieve the effect; alternatively an _additional_ element inserted into the row could be positioned accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a vertical line to the `article` element let's go with the simplest solution - CSS!

First, give the `article` element and `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. Then add a `:after` psuedo-element to create a vertical bar.

The HTML and Javascript have are untouched (except a small change to the borders on the article) so you only need to add a few lines of CSS.

```js
 var Parentdiv = document.getElementById("homeContainer");
 var rowDiv = document.createElement("article");
 rowDiv.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12");
 rowDiv.style.marginBottom = "1px";
 rowDiv.style.marginTop = "1px";
 rowDiv.style.borderTop = "2px solid #ddd";
 rowDiv.style.borderRight = "2px solid #ddd";
 rowDiv.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #ddd";
 rowDiv.style.borderLeft = "2px solid #ddd";
 Parentdiv.appendChild(rowDiv);
```

```css
#homeContainer article {
  height: 300px;           // Just for demo purposes since we have no content
  position: relative;
}

#homeContainer article:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 3px solid #000000;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="widget-grid" class="" style="padding-left:13px;padding-right:13px;">
  <div class="row" id="homeContainer"></div>
  <div class="modaldialogs" style="display: none">
    <div class="center">
      <img alt="" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the problem is here as I told I don't want in the article I want the same for id that is why I am trying to change in javascript. And second as the box is forming dynamically one by one they overlapping the line

Comment: if I change in HTML this changed is applied everywhere.

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete example.

Comment: the HTML code which is I am using it is used to make more text boxes like these so there will be one box then again in bottom but I only want a line in first or top one. So, I have given different ids to the text box from which I get distinguish. In my JavaScript as you can see I first check id then I am proceeding. But the solution append border to each box which is not the correct solution. Hope now I am clear

Comment: Ok, sounds like you need a slight change. We only need to target the `article` elements within the `#metricBar` element?

Comment: You just need to change the CSS selector to target the `article` elements within the `#Metricbar` element.

Comment: Can you share a complete example of your HTML including the `#Metricbar` element?

Comment: The `#Metricbar` element isn't shown in your HTML code.

Comment: yes it is not in HTML code but id=homeContainer which is what in javascript code. It is a dynamic HTML based on input we can make use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134685/discussion-between-brett-dewoody-and-shv22).

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. We can have a new div by using javascript and a new class name which will have a border-left.

This is my solution

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.className = "divider";
rowDiv.appendChild(element); \\appending it to parent
```

CSS

```
.divider {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  border-left: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
}
```